# Can we get sued for copying the same drawing style?

Tags: legal, comics

Akira Toriyama's Dragon Ball & Square Enix's Dragon Quest share the same art style, but it's because they were designed by the same artist, Akira Toriyama. I am wondering if we can get sued for using the same art style, same faces, but different settings. Let's say we're writing a vampire comic and our characters look like the characters from Dragon Ball or Dragon Quest. Can we get sued for this?

Comment: Maybe needs country and/or jurisdiction, but there's [a YouTube video in Japanese (English CC) talking about this with a Japanese lawyer](https://youtu.be/gTItOTCA1gI?t=1958).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copyright does not protect the drawing style**, ideas, and concept. It only protects that **no one should reproduce any of your actual artwork** without your permission.

A quote from https://www.artslaw.com.au/article/i-like-your-style-part-i-copyright-infringement-or-not/ is as follows:

"You cannot copyright a style or technique. Copyright only protects you from someone else reproducing one of your actual artworks – not from someone else coming up with their own work in the same style."

You may also refer to the following link about this topic:

https://www.thelegalartist.com/blog/you-cant-copyright-style